# WAF - ntldd - Unable to link static system library

Tags: c, gcc, build, waf

Those familiar with Unix will know the `ldd` program. It lists shared library dependencies of a given executable. There is a Windows clone called [ntldd](https://github.com/LRN/ntldd).

`ntldd` has a very simple build script:

```
gcc -fno-common -g -O3 -Wall -D_WIN32_WINNT=0x501 -c libntldd.c -o libntldd.o
ar rs libntldd.a libntldd.o
gcc -fno-common -g -O3 -Wall -L. ntldd.c -lntldd -limagehlp -o ntldd.exe
```

The build script works.

What an ideal little program to test [WAF](http://code.google.com/p/waf/) with, I thought.

This is the wscript I thought would work:

```py
#! /usr/bin/env python

from waflib import Logs

APPNAME = "ntldd"

top = "."
out = "build"

def options(ctx):
    ctx.load("compiler_c")

def configure(ctx):
    ctx.load("compiler_c")
    ctx.env.append_value("DEFINES", "_WIN32_WINNT=0x501")

    if ctx.env.CC_NAME == "gcc":
        ctx.env.CFLAGS = ["-g", "-fno-common", "-O3"]
    ctx.check_cc(stlib = "imagehlp", linkflags = "-static")

def build(ctx):
    ctx.logger = Logs.make_logger("build/build.log", "build")
    ctx.env.BINDIR = "binaries"
    ctx.env.LIBDIR = ctx.env.BINDIR

    # a C library
    ctx\
    (
        features = ["c", "cstlib"],
        source   = "libntldd.c",
        target   = "_ntldd",
    )

    # a C application
    ctx\
    (
        features  = ["c", "cprogram"],
        source    = "ntldd.c",
        target    = "ntldd",
        use       = ["_ntldd", "imagehlp"],
    )
```

But NO!

WAF reckons I never told it to link a static library, `imagehlp`, for the executable.

From the build.log:

```
['D:\\mingw-builds\\x64-4.8.1-posix-seh-rev5\\mingw64\\bin\\gcc.exe', '-Wl,--enable-auto-import', 'ntldd.c.2.o', '-o', 'C:\\Users\\Administrator\\Documents\\Projects\\ntldd\\build\\ntldd.exe', '-Wl,-Bstatic', '-L.', '-l_ntldd', '-Wl,-Bdynamic']
err: .\lib_ntldd.a(libntldd.c.1.o): In function `BuildDepTree':
C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\Projects\ntldd\build/../libntldd.c:235: undefined reference to `__imp_MapAndLoad'
C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\Projects\ntldd\build/../libntldd.c:441: undefined reference to `__imp_UnMapAndLoad'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Note that it complains that it can't find `MapAndLoad` and `UnMapAndLoad`; both functions are in `imagehlp`.

What's going on?

Answer (score 2):

You should be using the `stlib` dictionary key to list existing system static libraries that you want to link (it looks like `use` is only for referencing other items you have produced in the same `Waf` build).

```
# a C application
ctx\
(
    features  = ["c", "cprogram"],
    source    = "ntldd.c",
    target    = "ntldd",
    use       = ["_ntldd"],
    stlib     = ["imagehlp"],
)
```

I found this in [section 10.3 of the Waf Book](https://waf.io/book/#_library_interaction_use). The API docs were not helpful.

Comment: Actually, you can reference system libraries in `use=` BUT they must be configured FIRST during `configure`. I was missing the `uselib_store` parameter when checking for `imagehlp`.